# Download a file in D

Tags: networking, download, d

How do I download a file in D? I have checked out the standard library, and the sample. I would rather use phobos with the newest dmd2 than tango. All I need to do is download a file (hopefully using std.socket and std.socketstream). Could also use etc.c.curl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

etc.c.curl provides the C bindings for curl, so you could use that. That's really the only way that I know of to do it using Phobos at the moment, unless you want to do it with std.socket and handle the HTTP requests and responses yourself (which I assume that you don't really want to do).

However, a D wrapper for the C curl bindings is currently in review in the [digitalmars.D](http://www.digitalmars.com/NewsGroup.html) newsgroup, which would give you a D API for interacting with curl. Assuming that it passes review (which it probably will, though it may change a fair bit during the review process), it'll end up in Phobos. Once it's merged in, it'll be in the following release. So, it'll probably be in either 2.055 or 2.056, depending on when 2.055 gets released.

Until then, however, you're pretty much going to need to either use the C bindings or download the D curl wrapper currently under review. You can find the documentation [here](http://freeze.steamwinter.com/D/web/phobos/etc_curl.html) and the code [here](https://github.com/jcd/phobos/blob/curl-wrapper/etc/curl.d) if you want to try it out. If you do that however, it would be much appreciated if you chimed in on the review in the newsgroup to give feedback on it so that it can be appropriately ironed out and improved prior to inclusion in Phobos.

Comment: Alright, I don't want to use tango, but it _feels_ more complete and clean than phobos, and as a java dev, I want a nice cushy std set of libraries :-) however, this is probably one of the few times I use this. Thank you for your replies Jonathan!

Comment: For the most part, Phobos is newer than Tango. Tango is so much better than Phobos for D1, because it has had a community working on it whereas it was primarily Walter Bright working Phobos, and he was working primarily on the compiler, and Phobos didn't get anywhere near as much work done on it. Phobos in D2 is definitely more community-driven and making good progress, but it's newer, and it takes time for it to grow. Eventually it should rival Tango in terms of functionality, but it still lacks much of what Tango can do.

Comment: For instance, I am putting the finishing touches on an application which downloads my file, then compares its Md5 and Sha256 sums to ones stored online. It would have literally been imposiible for me to figure that out with phobos. But for the most part I do use phobos.

Comment: let's hope that the now open source D2's phobos expands to what tango is, now that Tango is done, maybe not abandoned, but source is updated rarely these days